# react native gesture handler and react native skia not updating when drawing on App unless App is reloaded

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using react native to create a drawing app using react native skia and react native gesture handler, this is my code for that screen

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  PanGestureHandler,

} from "../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Canvas, Path } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";



export default function Draw() {
  const [paths, setPaths] = useState([[]]);

  const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart((g) => {
      const newPaths = paths;
      newPaths.push(["M " + g.x + " " + g.y]);
      setPaths(newPaths);

    })
    .onUpdate((g) => {
        const newPaths = paths;
        newPaths[newPaths.length-1].push("L " + g.x + " " + g.y);
        setPaths(newPaths);
    })
    .minDistance(1)

  return (
       <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
          <Canvas style={{flex:1}} collapsable={false}>
        {paths.map((p, index) => (
            
              <Path
                key={index}z
                path={p.join(" ")}
                strokeWidth={5}
                style="stroke"
                color={"black"}
              />
            ))}
          </Canvas>
      </GestureDetector>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import ScoutingSheet from './screens/ScoutingSheet';
import QRCodeScanner from './screens/QRCodeScanner';
import Draw from './screens/AutonCanvas';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {

  // Initialize Firebase
  render() {
    return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
          
          <Stack.Screen name="AutonCanvas" component={Draw} />

          <Stack.Screen name="ScoutingSheet" component={ScoutingSheet} />

          <Stack.Screen name="QrCodeScanner" component={QRCodeScanner} />



        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>

    );
  }
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "roboticsscoutingapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "0.1.172",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.3.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.3",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^9.6.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The problem is that, whenever I pan my finger on the screen, no drawing shows up, but when I refresh the app, the SVG image suddenly shows up in the correct place, is it a problem with my packages or something else?

I tried changing my react native gesture handler version but that did not fix anything, I also moved my GestureHandlerRoot to my App.js from my Draw function, where it was previously

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mutating `paths`. This probably leads to React not recognising any change.

Try `const newPaths = [...paths];`
instead of `const newPaths = paths;`

If this works we can conclude that mutation was the problem. But I also don't think it's a good idea to copy the array on every update (stroke).

I think it would be better to have a separate variable for `currentPath`. You could then push `currentPath` onto `paths` in the `onEnd()` event.

With a separate `currentPath` variable you need to render this path separately.

Pseudo code for what I mean:

```
const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = getState([]);

const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart((g) => {
      setCurrentPath(["M " + g.x + " " + g.y]);
    })
    .onUpdate((g) => {
      setCurrentPath(...currentPath, "L " + g.x + " " + g.y);
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      setPaths([...paths, currentPath]);
      setCurrentPath([]);
    })
    .minDistance(1)
```

In the render block, add a separate `<Path>` for currentPath.

```
<Path
   key={'currentPath'}
   path={currentPath.join(" ")}
   strokeWidth={5}
   style="stroke"
   color={"black"}
/>
```

N.B.
I'm not sure if separating currentPath will do much optimization. Try without it first. I can imagin if `paths` holds massive amounts of paths, the array copying might take some time. But I'm actually guessing. Maybe Hermes or V8 is bonkers fast on this operation.

N.B.2
I don't know if the `<Path>` component can handle an empty path. If not you'll need to render it conditionally.

N.B.3
I'm not sure if there is an `onEnd()` event. But something alike surely exists.